# How to get actual keys from MongoDB result array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, key

**INPUT:**

```
  let array =[
                {name:"xyz", email:"xyz@gmail.com", date:"22/10/2020" },
                {name:"abc", email:"abc@gmail.com", date:"29/12/2020" },
                {name:"efg", email:"efg@gmail.com", date:"20/01/2021" },
                {name:"pqr", email:"pqr@gmail.com", date:"12/08/2020", age:"20" },
                {name:"stu", email:"stu@gmail.com", date:"19/09/2020", age:"21" },
               ]
```

After performing certain operations I got the above array of objects as output from mongodb collection. From that array I want to get all keys and compare each and every object in an array and if any property present in any object not there in another object then I want to assign the property with empty string value.
To perform that operation I have written the code as shown below-

```
 const keys = array.reduce(
                    (acc, curr) => (Object.keys(curr).forEach((key) => acc.add(key)), acc),
                    new Set()
                  );
                  
                  const output = array.map((item) =>
                    [...keys].reduce((acc, key) => ((acc[key] = item[key] ?? ""), acc), {})
                  );
```

By performing above operations along with my original keys I am getting unnecessary keys like "$__",  "$isNew", "_doc"

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
 [
        {
            "$__": {
                "activePaths": {
                    "paths": {
                        "_id": "init"
                    },
                    "states": {
                        "ignore": {},
                        "default": {},
                        "init": {
                            "_id": true
                        },
                        "modify": {},
                        "require": {}
                    },
                    "stateNames": [
                        "require",
                        "modify",
                        "init",
                        "default",
                        "ignore"
                    ]
                },
                "strictMode": false,
                "skipId": true,
                "selected": {},
                "fields": {},
                "exclude": null
            },
            "$isNew": false,
            "_doc": {
                "_id": "62e6791b049e103f612f0882",
                "name": "pqr",
                "email": "pqr@gmail.com",
                "date": "12/8/2020",
                "age": "20",
               
            },
            "name": "pqr",
            "email": "pqr@gmail.com",
            "date": "12/8/2020",
            "age": "20",
           
           
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "date": "22/10/2020",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "date": "29/12/2020",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "efg",
            "email": "efg@gmail.com",
            "date": "20/01/2021",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "pqr",
            "email": "pqr@gmail.com",
            "date": "12/08/2020",
            "age": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "stu",
            "email": "stu@gmail.com",
            "date": "19/09/2020",
            "age": "21"
        }
    ]
```

If I am using same code for normal array instead of resultant array from mongoodb I am getting correct output.
Please help me in resolving the above issue.

Comment: add `.lean()` to your query if you are using mongoose as shown here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Answer (score 0):

Query

- if you have few fields and you know their names you can do it on server like bellow, in simple way
- check if field (if missing it will be false) if its there keep old value, else add it with ""
- the bellow doesn't work with boolean fields, if you have those you should check if `type="missing"` but in your case you dont have boolean fields so it will be ok

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62e7065878a49d878285146f)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"name": {"$cond": ["$name", "$name", ""]},
    "email": {"$cond": ["$email", "$email", ""]},
    "date": {"$cond": ["$date", "$date", ""]},
    "age": {"$cond": ["$age", "$age", ""]}}}])
```